# android license for jar file from 3rd library

Tags: android

I'm creating a new app using Android studio, and I used jar file of Universal image loader.

in https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader has license.

I know I need to add license for library, but I don't know how to do that.

**My questions**

how to add license of it in may app?

need to show it when app open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is licence placed in all the files of the project. The only thing that you have to do is just don't remove this from files.

> how to add license of it in may app?

Just Add this code in your files, which is already there so you don't have to do anything.

```
 /*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Sergey Tarasevich
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *******************************************************************************/
```

> need to show it when app open?

No, you don't have to display it to the user, however it should remain somewhere in your source code.

Note: If you show the name of owner or his library reference in app's about section or third party libraries section, that would be a good credit to the code owner.

Comment: Add license code in license.txt in asset folder or in java file I use library

Comment: Its up to you where you want to put it, but it should remain present somewhere in the source code, in case it gets deleted or removed intentionally or accidentally, license terms will be breached. Basically the point is that license should remain in the source code throughout the life of the application.

Comment: sorry you so much because my English not good and this is first time I create android app. that mean I place license in all java file or just mainactivity java file? or just place it in license.txt in asset folder?

Comment: Add license.txt file. Thats it. :)